# extracting entire xml node

Tags: jquery, xml

I'm using jquery/ajax (and stuck using IE7. I know, right?) and getting an xml response and iterating over the nodes to extract the data I also need to extract the entire "Query" node and display it because it's a CAML query that will vary from view to view. (All of this is going out to a text file for use in documentation, hence the need).

I've tried converting the node to a string using strQry = $(this).find("View").find("Query").xml but I'm getting "undefined"

I've even tried the following with no success:

```
  var strQry = $(this).find("View").find("Query").text() ; // undefined
  var strQry = $(this).find("View").find("Query").innerHTML() ; // error
  var strQry = $(this).find("View").find("Query").outerHTML() ;// error
  var strQry = $(this).find("View").find("Query") ;// [object Object]
  var strQry = $('<div>').append($(this).find("View").find("Query").clone()).remove().html(); // blank
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

My XML looks like:

```
<List Name="ListName" Title="Tasks" Description="" Url="Lists/Tasks" >
<MetaData>
  <Views>           
   <View Name="Tasks Due Today" DisplayName="Due Today" Url="Lists/Tasks/duetoday.aspx" >
    <ViewFields>
     <FieldRef Name="ID"/><FieldRef Name="Field1"/><FieldRef Name="Field2"/><FieldRef Name="Created"/><FieldRef Name="Field3"/><FieldRef Name="Field4"/><FieldRef Name="Field5"/><FieldRef Name="Date"/>
    </ViewFields>
    <Query>
     <GroupBy Collapse="FALSE" GroupLimit="100"><FieldRef Name="Field1"/></GroupBy><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="Field2"/></OrderBy><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Date"/><Value Type="DateTime"><Today/></Value></Eq></Where>
    </Query>
   </View>
  </Views>
</MetaData>
</List>
```

TIA!

CG

Comment: This could help: `$(this)` returns a jQuery Object `$(this)[0]` returns a HTML DOM Object. Did you try `.html()`?

Comment: Thanks Bondye. I have also tried .html() unsuccessfully. It gave an "innerHTML is null or undefined" error.

Comment: I wrote you a little example. Hope it helps! http://jsfiddle.net/Q47j5/

Comment: Thanks. But you are only extracting the text of a text node. I need to pull the entire <query> node.